# How to make an "always on top" application on top of push notifications?

Tags: unity, notification, electron

I have an Electron application which uses [`alwaysOnTop`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window), but the problem is push notifications can still appear on top. I do not want to disable notifications; they should still work. But for this application, nothing should be able to draw on top of it. What are my options? I'm currently using the default desktop environment but am open to modifications if that is required.

Comment: It's not clear to me how this relates to Ubuntu. Could you explain?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu Unity 22.10 ?   Why not tell us and require us to guess?

Comment: I am currently supporting 14.04 and 20.04, will not need 14.04 support soon.

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is in extended support and now Ubuntu 14.04 ESM thus only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage and off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Happy to accept an answer here that addresses the current release!